# Listview bugs after add 9 items

Tags: c#

I'm having some trouble in my C# program.

After adding 9 items, the programs bugs, when im trying to add the 10th item, it only shows blank spaces.

```
private void btnConfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int NumeroUtente;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNomeUtente.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTelefoneUtente.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmailUtente.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbbPulseira.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não podem existir campos vazios!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            // Utentes na Fila de Atendimento
            if (ListasFilas.FilaAtendimento.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Erro: Não existem utentes na fila!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            else
                // Utente repetido
                if (txtNumeroUtente.Enabled == true && LV_Repetido(Convert.ToInt32(txtNumeroUtente.Text)) == true)
                    MessageBox.Show("Erro: Utente repetido!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                else
                {
                    // Cria novo utente
                    if (NovoUtente == true)
                    {
                        // Nº Utente
                        NumeroUtente = Atribui_Num_Utente();
                        // Adiciona à ListaUtentes
                        ListasFilas.ListaUtentes.Add(new Utente(NumeroUtente, txtNomeUtente.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtTelefoneUtente.Text), txtEmailUtente.Text));
                        //switch (cbbPulseira.Text)
                        //{
                        //    case "Verde": ListasFilas.FilaAtVerde.Enqueue(NumeroUtente); break;
                        //    case "Amarela": ListasFilas.FilaAtAmarelo.Enqueue(NumeroUtente); break;
                        //    case "Vermelha": ListasFilas.FilaAtVermelho.Enqueue(NumeroUtente); break;
                        //    case "Roxa": ListasFilas.FilaAtRoxo.Enqueue(NumeroUtente); break;
                        //}
                        // Atribui número
                        //NumeroUtente = Atribui_Num_Utente();
                    }
                    // Utente existente
                    else
                    {
                        NumeroUtente = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumeroUtente.Text);
                    }
                    // Bug encontrado
                    if(lblSenha.Text == "10")
                    MessageBox.Show("Bug: Quando chega à senha 10 não mostra os campos na listview!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                    // Adiciona à listview

                    int cntItems = lvUtentes.Items.Count;

                    lvUtentes.Items.Add(lblSenha.Text); // Senha
                    lvUtentes.Items[cntItems].SubItems.Add(NumeroUtente.ToString()); // Nº
                    lvUtentes.Items[cntItems].SubItems.Add(txtNomeUtente.Text); // Nome
                    lvUtentes.Items[cntItems].SubItems.Add(cbbPulseira.Text); // Fila Cor

                    // Adiciona à Fila Cores
                    switch (cbbPulseira.Text)
                    {
                        case "Verde": ListasFilas.FilaAtVerde.Enqueue(NumeroUtente); break;
                        case "Amarela": ListasFilas.FilaAtAmarelo.Enqueue(NumeroUtente); break;
                        case "Vermelha": ListasFilas.FilaAtVermelho.Enqueue(NumeroUtente); break;
                        case "Roxa": ListasFilas.FilaAtRoxo.Enqueue(NumeroUtente); break;
                    }

                    // Próxima senha
                    lblSenha.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(lblSenha.Text) + 1).ToString();
                    ListasFilas.FilaAtendimento.Dequeue(); // Retira o próximo utente da fila
```

Im not seeing where is the problem, when i try to debug, watching it code by code it works, but when add's to the listview, i just got blank spaces.

Thank you.

EDIT: After some tests i figured out that it bugs when:

- lblSenha.text passes from 9 to 10.
- lblSenha.text passes from 99 to 100.

When lblsenha.text starts at 10 doesnt bug until 99.

Comment: What mviewmode? what does all the spanish(?) mean? what about the items count?

Comment: @TaW watch the edit please

Comment: Have you tried increasing the column widths?